# Android, delete files in my data directory?

Tags: android, version, delete-file

My application stores some files that are required for it to run in the data directory of the app

```
/data/data/com.example.myapp/files/filehere.file
```

When my application is updated from the market, it is important that I clear the files in the data directory, and update them to the latest ones from the new package that has just been downloaded.

My question is, how do I programatically delete the files in the directory in question?

Alternatively, is there an alternative directory that I can store the files in that are persistent across the lifetime of my application version, but will be cleared once an update is installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
File file = new File(FILEPATH);
if(file.exists())
  file.delete();
```

As for your last question, my guess is you'll have to control that on your upgrade process. f.e., create a directory for each version and manage the files inside when the user upgrades.

Comment: I re-wrote this into a recrsive function taht sorts through the directory, but essentially this is the correct mechanism so I have accepted it as the correct answer.

Comment: You're right, I should have written how to clean the full directory, I only focused on deleting the file. My apologies and thanks for choosing it anyway as the right answer. If you paste the code I'll update the answer.

Comment: As the comments above mention, this method will not work if FILEPATH references a directory which contains files/directories. For the delete() method to work on a directory, the directory must be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using a [database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) wrapped in [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). You can then use the onUpgrade function to detect a new app version.