# Delete file in data directory

Tags: android, delete-file, datadirectory

I have the same problem like in [Android, delete files in my data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637835/android-delete-files-in-my-data-directory)

But it is not working for me.

```
String sourcefile = getFilesDir().toString() + "/aaa.jpk";
File file = new File(sourcefile);
file.delete();
```

That should be the easiest way to delete that file but somehow I can't do it.
The permissions are added to android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

so that not the problem. That string is leads me to file :

```
data/data/com.example.program/files/aaa.jpk
```

Where is my problem actually? I can't figure that out.

Code for downloading file:

```
 dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
 Uri resource = Uri.parse("http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(resource);
 request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
 request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), null, "aaa");
 request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
 request.setTitle("a.xml");

 dm.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use concatenation to create a path. Use `File file=new File(getFilesDir(), "aaa.jpk");` and see if that helps. Note that your permissions are irrelevant here, as you are working with internal storage, not external storage.

Comment: thanks for a quick answer. Unfortunately it isn't working. I've tried so many things and nothing is working.

Comment: @user2647384: Given that file path, you are also welcome to use `deleteFile("aaa.jpk");`. If you cannot delete the file, how did you create it in the first place?

Comment: At first time i download it by program, later on when i couldn't delete it so i thought this could work with the file i will create myself using some file explorer. It Didn't work either. code for the download of a file in first post

Comment: @JustPeter: You are downloading to external storage. You are trying to delete from internal storage. This is akin to downloading to one hard drive and trying to delete the file from a completely different hard drive.

Comment: I know the difference between internal and external storage, but i didn't know that i am looking at different places. I'll post later when i will have some results.

Comment: @JustPeter: You are calling `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()` on the `DownloadManager.Request`, which puts the files in `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `getFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using terminal emulator on rooted phone/tablet its no problem by simply "cd" to folder containing the file and then "su" to request root access and "rm aaa.jpk" it will remove the file

[HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Guide%3aUsing_the_Terminal) you will find in-depth information on how to use terminal emulator and adb commands