# Deleting files from applications data folder

Tags: android

I have a tablet where I need to execute a service from a binary file which will continually receive data from a chip and store the various data files in the "/data/data/com.example.binary/received/" folder. I also have a FileObserver set up on that folder to perform an action on the files that are created and once the Close event is given by the FileObserver I an trying to delete the file. This is what I have an issue with. I **can delete the files if it is in the "/data/data/com.example.binary/" folder** but **if its in the "/data/data/com.example.binary/received/" folder I cant delete it**. Seems to be some android permission issue. Is there any way around this?.

So far I have tried and failed by

1) trying to execute the "rm /data/data/com.example.binary/received/file1.xy"

2) trying file.delete()

FYI - I have the Read and Write Permissions. And all file handles to the file are closed, that's when the file's Close event is fired by the FileObserver.

I **can delete the files from ADB using the "rm file1.xy"**

And the binary file is from our client and i cannot change the location where it creates the output files.xy . . it will always be in the received folder. So any suggestions?

PS: /data/data folder is the location where all the installed apps get stored in my tablet.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637835/android-delete-files-in-my-data-directory

Comment: that's the problem its not in my app data path. its created in a custom directory inside my app path .

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card
+ check your permissions.

Comment: I already mentioned that I have the permission and can delete files that are present directly in the /data/data/com.comp.app/ folder. I think my fiel handle is not released somewhere.

Comment: Have u found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have faced this issue but first, check your file exist then try to delete. In my situation i didn't pay attention to add file extension, thats`s why _file.exists()_ returns false.